# Positioning video overlay in mobile view

Tags: html, css

There is `div` including video element and an overlay with a brown background on like below. I am unable to position the overlay in <767px view. I tried flexbox and flex-direction: column but the element is still unresponsive. Its position is exactly the same as on large screens and does not change like it was shown in second screen. The current result is screen no. 2. The intended effect is shown in screen no. 3.

My code:

```
<div className="background-video">
  <video id="video" autoPlay="loop" muted="" loop="">
    <source src={work} type="video/mp4"></source>
  </video>
  <div className="brown-be">
   <div className="me-modal"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.background-video {
  position: relative;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

#video {
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.brown-be {
  background-color: rgba(157,124,94,1);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 65%;
  height: 60%;
  z-index: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .brown-be {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

**Screen Nº1**

[image: Screeen Nº1]

**Screen Nº2**

[image: Screen Nº2]

**Screen Nº3**

[image: Screen Nº3]

Comment: Hey there, I'd like to help you, but your question is kinda confusing and it lacks some code.

I can see what you're going for, but I'm not able to quickly test this in something like Codepen with the code provided.

If you can temporarily put this online somewhere, or replicate this issue somewhere, I should be able to do some testing.

Comment: @spoochy Link: r9f56.csb.app/about